# Cascade image without space between them

Tags: html, css, image, class

Have added four images and need to cascade them together, however cannot, cause space is created between them across.its only connected the image below but across cannot,I have added an image to show the result I am after

html

```
<div class="content-box-left-bootomgrids">
    <div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid">

        <img src="images/room2.jpg" title="image-name" />
        <img src="images/Ocean.jpg" title="image-name" />
    </div>

    <div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid">
        <h3>Welcome</h3>
        <p><img src="images/room3.jpg" title="image-name" />
        <img src="images/garden.jpg" title="image-name" /></p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid lastgrid">
        <img src="images/room3.jpg" title="image-name" />
        <img src="images/exec.jpg" title="image-name" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-box-left-bootomgrids {
    padding: 0em 0 0em 0;
}

.content-box-left-bootomgrid img{
    background:#FFF;
    padding:0px;
    display:block;
    width: 93%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

Expected  result i need
[Result image i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtSgc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this CSS/HTML combination. I wrote is as a beginner can understand. And you need to learn more about different CSS properties.

```css
.content-box-left-bootomgrids {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
.content-box-left-bootomgrid img {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box-left-bootomgrids">
  <div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid">
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid">
    <img src="images/room3.jpg" title="image-name" />
    <img src="images/garden.jpg" title="image-name" />
  </div>
  <div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid">
    <img src="images/room2.jpg" title="image-name" />
    <img src="images/Ocean.jpg" title="image-name" />
  </div>
  <div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid lastgrid">
    <img src="images/room3.jpg" title="image-name" />
    <img src="images/exec.jpg" title="image-name" />
  </div>
</div>
```